# Ordenação com heapsort

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, classificação

Quando a ordenação é feita com o *heapsort* e os candidatos para a raíz da árvore forem **iguais**, a ordem de prioridade é dada para o elemento de maior ou menor índice no vetor **original** ou é dada pela posição que estes elementos ocupam na árvore (prioridade para o lado esquerdo pelo menor índice)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, a pergunta se refere à primeira parte do algoritmo, que é a construção do *heap*.

Como as implementações tradicionais do *heapsort* (`siftDown`) utilizam uma estrutura de árvore armazenada em um array, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

Dada a ávore inicial armazenada em um array:

```
v = { 1, 9a, 9b, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

A estrutura da ávore é:

```
      .. 1 ..
     /       \
    /         \
   9a         9b
  /  \       /  \
 /    \     /    \
3      4   5      6
```

Os elementos iguais (`9`), aqui, são representados como `9a` e `9b`.

E conforme um exemplo de implementação em linguagem C, extraído da Wikipedia em:
[Wikipedia - Heapsort - Código em C](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#C.C3.B3digo_em_C)

```
void heapsort(int a[], int n) {

   int i = n / 2, pai, filho, t;

   for (;;) {
      if (i > 0) {
          i--;
          t = a[i];
      } else {
          n--;
          if (n == 0) return;
          t = a[n];
          a[n] = a[0];
      }

      pai = i;

      //Primeiro será feita a comparação com o filho da esquerda.
      filho = i * 2 + 1;

      while (filho < n) {

         // Se o filho da esquerda for menor do que o filho da direita,
         // então será feita a troca do filho que será comparado.
          if ((filho + 1 < n)  &&  (a[filho + 1] > a[filho]))
              filho++;
          if (a[filho] > t) {
             a[pai] = a[filho];
             pai = filho;
             filho = pai * 2 + 1;
          } else {
             break;
          }
      }
      a[pai] = t;
   }
}
```

No momento da escolha entre os candidatos iguais, quem vai para a raíz é o `9a` (filho esquerdo), pois na comparação:

```
a[filho + 1] > a[filho]
```

o valor (no vetor), indexado pela variável `filho` (`9a` "no lado esquerdo") é **igual** ao valor armazenado no índice `filho+1` (`9b` "no lado direito"), portanto, o índice filho não é incrementado (na linha `filho++`).

O comentário no código também confirma que a comparação sempre é feita a partir do lado esquerdo da árvore:

```
//Primeiro será feita a comparação com o filho da esquerda.
```

Minha conclusão, a partir das premissas:

- análise do algoritmo (eu não testei)
- a pergunta se refere apenas a fase de construção do *heap*
- a forma como a ávore é armazenada no array

é que a resposta correta é:

> a prioridade é dada pela posição que estes elementos ocupam na árvore
>   (prioridade para o lado esquerdo pelo menor índice)

---

Referências utilizadas para elaborar a resposta:

<sub>KNUTH, Donald Ervin. **The Art of Computer Programming**: v.3 - Sorting and Searching. 2nd Edition. Westford (MA): Addison-Wesley Professional, 2012. 782 p (Volumes 1-4A Boxed Set)

`ISBN-13:978-0321751041`

Páginas consultadas: 144 a 148</sub>

<sub>PRESS, William et al. **Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific  Computing**. 2nd Edition. New York (NY): Cambridge University Press, 1992. 994 p (reimpresso em 2002 e corrigido para o software versão 2.10)

`ISBN-13: 978-0521431088`

Páginas consultadas: 336 a 338</sub>

<sub>ATALLAH, Mikhail J. et al. **Algorithms and Theory of Computation Handbook**.1st Edition. Boca Raton (FL):CRC Press, 1312 p (Chapman & Hall/CRC Applied Algorithms and Data Structures series (Book 1))

`ISBN-13: 978-0849326493`

Páginas consultadas: 3-7 e 3-8</sub>

---

Links complementares, para referência online:

[Wikipedia - Heapsort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

[Wikipedia - Ordenação estável](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o_est%C3%A1vel)

[Wikipedia - Heapsort - em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) - o texto está mais completo e tem um "passo-a-passo" do algoritmo)

[Wikipedia - Heap](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap)

[LANG, HANS WERNER - Heapsort](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/heap/heapen.htm)

[Sorting Algorithm Animations - Heap Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/heap-sort)